# Scroll an image vertically in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I have an image and i want to scroll that image vertically(up and down). I am using the following code to scroll vertically. But if i go up, it is going up. If i release touch it automatically goes down. I want it stop there.

```
CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
CCLayer *layer = CCLayer::create();
layer->setAnchorPoint(CCPointZero);

CCSprite *spr=CCSprite::create("img.png");
spr->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width*0.5f,winSize.height*0.1f));
layer->setContentSize( CCSizeMake( winSize.widht, winSize.height));
layer->addChild( spr );


CCScrollView *scrollView =    CCScrollView::create(winSize, layer);
scrollView->retain();
scrollView->setContentSize(CCSizeMake(layer->getContentSize().width,layer->getContentSize().height));
scrollView->setDirection( cocos2d::extension::kCCScrollViewDirectionVertical );
scrollView->setPosition( ccp( 0,0 ) );
scrollView->setContainer( layer );

this->addChild(scrollView);
scrollView->setContentOffset( CCPointZero );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following code in your code:

```
scrollView->setBounceEnabled(false);
```

Worked for me. I hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting the following error saying that No member named in setBounceEnabled in CCScrollView.

Comment: i want it scroll up/down Whenever i want. But i can't scroll again if i use setbounceenabled.